# Azure AppService URL Rewriting

Tags: azure, iis, url-rewriting, .net-core

I have three web applications that I am trying to host in one single AppService in Azure. 
One of the Web Applications is a simple SPA Angular App and the other two are ASP.NET Core WebAPI Applications.

Each of the two WebAPI apps have their routes defined in code as;

```
/api/{endpoint}
```

These routes cannot be changed and must remain as is.

In my AppService, I have multiple Virtual Directories defined to host all these separate applications.

the directory structure is as follows;
[image: AppService Directory Structure]

The Angular app is hosted in the /atlanta and /colton virtual directories and is accessible without issue.

Each of the WebAPI Applications are hosted in each of the other two Virtual Directories.

When the angular app makes a request to one of the APIs, it issues an HTTP request to either `/{region}/api` or `/{region}/security` respectively.

The issue I am having is that the APIs are returning 404 errors because the route `/{region}/security/{endpoint}` is not defined. The correct route would be `/api/{endpoint}`.

I am pretty sure I can resolve this issue by using URL Rewriting in my web.config, but thus far I have been unable to get this work correctly. Here is one of my URL Rewrite attempts;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <globalRules>
          <rule name="SecurityAPI">
            <match url="/atlanta/security/*" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/api/{R:0}"  />
          </rule>
        </globalRules>
      </rewrite>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="/atlanta/security/*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments="HMS.Security.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

How can I resolve this issue and get the HTTP requests to get routed to the correct endpoints?

Comment: have you tried using the `UseStaticFiles()` configuration for this? If you can configure the same there, it will be much easier to test and your code would be portable if you need to move it away from azure web apps someday

Comment: check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2#serve-files-outside-of-web-root